# Stop Visual Studio Code from Opening Submodules in Source Control View

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I open a Git project that contains submodules, VSCode additionally opens all submodules in the source control view. This clutters the source control view, especially for projects with 10+ submodules.

How do I make VSCode only open the current "root" Git project?

Here, for example, `accel...` is the "root" project and `unive...` and `matpl...` are submodules.
[image]

I can go through all the submodules and close them manually, but this is pretty tedious.

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `git.detectSubmodules` setting like this:

```json
{
  "git.detectSubmodules": false
}
```

Comment: Mhh, interesting. I will try your solution as well

Comment: You are right, I think yours should be the solution.

Comment: FYI add to `settings.json` to make it repo specific

Answer (score 5):

I followed the answer given in here
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/53668#issuecomment-403398048
and it worked for me.

Go to VS Code settings (with `Ctrl+Shift+P` and type `settings` then click on `Preferences: Open Settings (UI)`) then search for `Git: Auto Repository Detection` and change it to `openEditors`.

When closing and reopening VS Code, submodules should not appear on the `Source Control` board.

Comment: This doesn't work. I have set `git.autoRepositoryDetection` to `openEditors`, but git submodules continue to appear in the "Source Control" tab.

Comment: Setting `git.detectSubmodules` to `false` worked, though.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options available to solve the problem:

1. Set `git.detectSubmodulesLimit` (`Git: Detect Submodules Limit` in UI) to 0.
2. Set `git.detectSubmodules` (`Git: Detect Submodules` in UI) to false.

First of all, press `Ctrl+Shift+P`, type `settings` and select one of two items you are most comfortable with:

- Preferences: Open Settings (UI)
- Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)

[image: Select settings]

If you are using the UI editor, search for `detect submodules` and then either uncheck `Detect Submodules` or set `Detect Submodules Limit` to `0`.

[image: "Detect Submodules" UI settings]

If you are more comfortable with `settings.json`, simply add either line within the curly brackets:

```json
{
    "git.detectSubmodulesLimit": 0,
    "git.detectSubmodules": false,
}
```

You don't need use both approaches at once - they do the trick independently.
After all, you may control the non-zero limit of detected submodules if you need it.